# Turning a list or user generated strings into a single string

Tags: python

I'm getting some input from users as a list of strings, ie:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

The strings could be anything from "hat" to a short essay. I need to store this list in my database as a string, and pull that string out and turn it back into a list later. Any advice on the safest / fastest way to do this? So far I've considered:

- [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html)
- [json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html)
- using a longish delimiter string (`&break;`)

Comment: There is no one correct answer,it depends on various details and even then it will come down to personal preference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yea I'm aware of that, I'm probably gonna end up with going with JSON (regardless of the answers) but figured this would generate good SO discussion

Comment: I would probably  use json too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference, so far, is msgpack (and xml). It has the canonical interface `protocol.dumps`/`protocol.loads` similar to `json` and support all Python base types similar to `json` and other packing libs.

- `json` is **readable** both by human and programs, *lot of tools* for it e.g. [jsonselect](http://jsonselect.org/#overview) or PostgreSQL.
- `pickle` is **handy** for *complex python types/classes* #lazy
- `msgpack` is performant speed & space wise. You can easily swap it with json and it's not "bloated". It works great with utf-8.
- `csv` is **ok** for lists and tables. It's more compact than json and easy to parse when it's under control #security. It can save *some CPU cyles & bandwidth*. It doesn't support nested lists by default.
- `xml` is portable, verbose, validation frameworks makes it easier to understand. It has loads of tools.

> using a longish delimiter string

This is looks like using a "rare" character, it can break. And if it matters, the longish thing can make it a performance burden.

> Neo4j

Since you are using Neo4J it's better to go with json for easier compatibility with the explorer.

**Tips:** never use `list` in protocols, it's good to have smallest possible messages but when there is a bug it's unreadable or clutter all the code. Backward compatibility is a burden. I prefer `dict` to represent objects and `list` to represent real lists or a `set` object. *Using a dictionary allow the application/protocol to self-document*. HTTP 1.x does that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you want to do is serializing the list to a file.
The [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) allows you to do that easily.

Here is an example:

```
import pickle
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    read_data = pickle.load(f)
print read_data
```

## EDIT

In case you wanna push your list to `Neo4J` database, you will have to use one of the [Python clients library](http://neo4j.com/developer/python/).
I will demonstrate how it can be done when using the [Py2neo](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo):

```
from py2neo import Node
list1 = Node("DataList", name="list1")
list1.properties['val'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
list1.push()
```

Of course, this is very **shallow** way to do that and probably you will do that in a different way -- depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Not saving it as a file, it's being saved in my database as a string

Comment: what db? mongodb? mysql? please be specific :)

Comment: [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/). It doesn't support double nested lists, or else I would just keep the content formatted as a list. Also (for people that know Neo4j / graph databases) the data in question is logically not suited for being placed on its own node.

Comment: Yup, that's why I mentioned that this is a __shallow__ way to do that. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Cyrin Did you check if http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/ supports nested documents? Maybe it's OrientDB specific. Happy to see you doing graphdb!

Comment: @amirouche at this point in the development process it might be less work to get neo4j to add nesting support, than it would be to switch databases

Comment: sounds interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serialize directly to a string you can use `pickle.dumps`:

```
import pickle
L = ['a','b','c','d']
pickle.dumps(L)
b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00dq\x04e.'
```

Comment: It's said that pickle can be unsafe #Repeater.